# How do I write R code to read directly from excel by specific cells?

Tags: r, excel, encoding

I am wondering a good place to start (perhaps helpful packages with examples, other similar questions, R functions/code starting place) to write R code that will pull directly from specific cells in an excel file and input it into a dataframe that can be used for analysis.

Full story: I get excel files as output from experiments reading 96-well plates. The excel files are in the shape of the plate. The excel file could look like the image below. In this case I would want to create a dataframe that has a row for each value, but a factor column that has a label attached to each color in the excel file image. I am imagining this to be done by specifying exact cell locations and hard coding? I'm somewhat newer to R, but have many books and other resources to use, which is why any suggestions for a good place to start would be helpful!

[Excel file example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkGFK.png)

Comment: The most basic package to look at might be `readxl`.

Comment: `tidyxl` is a package you could use for cell by cell operation. But it's a package less easy to use than the other suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `readxl::read_excel()` and `openxlsx::read.xlsx()` have arguments allowing the definition of specific ranges, namely `range` and `rows`/`cols`. Both also allow the definition of a `sheet`. see the `help` on those functions.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing data from 96-well experiments isn't trivial.  There are three main steps you need to take:

1. Read the data into a data frame.
2. Make the data frame "tidy".
3. Associate labels with the data.

#### Step 1: Load the data

The `readxl::read_excel()` function can be used to get the raw data into R from the Excel file.  There are other ways to do the same thing, but I like `readxl::read_excel()` because it's part of the `tidyverse`.  I'll show how to call this function in the next section.

#### Step 2: Tidy the data

Tidy data is much easier to work with than "messy" data.  If you're not familiar with the concept of tidy data, it's probably worth the time to read [this introduction](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/articles/tidy-data.html) or [this paper](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v059i10/v59i10.pdf).  Briefly, though, a data frame is tidy if:

- Each column is a single variable.
- Each row is a single observation.

In this case, that means we need:

- 4 columns:

  - "row_i", referring to a row on the plate, e.g. 0-7
  - "col_j", referring to a column on the plate, e.g. 0-11
  - "label", referring to the labels "Label 1" and "Label 2" specified in cells
    A4 and A13
  - "value", referring to the numeric values in the cells.
- 192 rows:

  - 96 for the "Label 1" plate, 96 for the "Label 2" plate.
  - We could have fewer rows if we were to exclude wells with no value, but
    there's not really any benefit to doing that.

Below is some code to load and tidy your data.  The `pivot_longer()` function  is what converts the plate-shaped data to tidy data.  If you aren't familiar with this function, [this vignette](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/articles/pivot.html) is a good introduction.

```
library(tidyverse)

# Load the "Label 1" and "Label 2" data separately, then combine then into a 
# single data frame afterwards.  This approach is pretty fragile (e.g. if a 
# "Label 3" were to be added, we'd have to change the code to account for 
# that), but unfortunately this data doesn't really lend itself to being parsed 
# robustly.

# Because the code for parsing the two plates will be pretty similar, we can 
# use a function to avoid repeating ourselves.
load_plate <- function(path, label, anchor) {
  readxl::read_excel(
        path,

        # Read an 8x12 block of cells.  There are easier ways to specify which 
        # cell to load (e.g. "B5:M12"), but using readxl::anchored() guarantees 
        # that the resulting data frame has the expected dimensions, which in 
        # turn simplifies the task of labeling the row and column indices.
        range=readxl::anchored(anchor, c(8, 12)),

        # The column indices aren't present in the Excel file, so we add them 
        # here.  The paste() function is necessary because column names have 
        # to be strings.  Later on we'll convert these names back to numbers 
        # and use them to populate the "col_j" column.
        col_names=paste(0:11),
      ) %>%

  # The row indices aren't present in the Excel file, so we add them here.  
  # We also add the label column, which is the same for all of these wells.
  mutate(
        row_i=0:7,
        label=label
      ) %>%

  pivot_longer(
        !c(row_i, label),
        names_to="col_j",
        names_transform=list(col_j=as.integer),
      )
}

data <- bind_rows(
      load_plate("path/to/data.xlsx", 1, "B5"),
      load_plate("path/to/data.xlsx", 2, "B14"),
)
```

#### Step 3: Label the data

The data frame now contains the data from the Excel file, but not the labels (e.g. blue/red/yellow/green).  I deal with a lot of microplate data myself, so I wrote a package called [wellmapr](https://wellmap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) specifically to add labels to this kind of data.  The basic approach facilitated by this package is to:

- Load the data into a tidy data frame.
- Load the layout into another tidy data frame.
- Merge the two data frames.

The first step is to create a separate file describing the layout of the plate.  The documentation linked above describes how to write these files, and they're usually pretty simple.  Below is a file that describes your data:

```
[row]
A.factor = "blue"
H.factor = "blue"

[col]
1.factor = "blue"
12.factor = "blue"

[block.1x3]
B2.factor = "red"
B3.factor = "yellow"
B4.factor = "green"
```

The next steps are to load the layout and to merge it with the data:

```
library(wellmapr)

layout <- wellmapr::load("path/to/layout.toml")

# This join works because both data frames have "row_i" and "col_j" columns 
# that contain 0-indexed row/column indices.  In fact, we intentionally prepared 
# the `data` data frame such that it would have these columns.
df <- inner_join(data, layout)
```

The end result is a data frame that combines the measured data ("value", "label") with the layout information ("factor") for each well:

```
# A tibble: 90 x 9
   row_i label col_j value well  well0 row   col   factor
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> 
 1     0     1     0   101 A1    A01   A     1     blue  
 2     0     1     1   104 A2    A02   A     2     blue  
 3     0     1     2   106 A3    A03   A     3     blue  
 4     0     1     3    99 A4    A04   A     4     blue  
 5     0     1     4    94 A5    A05   A     5     blue  
 6     0     1     5    96 A6    A06   A     6     blue  
 7     0     1     6    92 A7    A07   A     7     blue  
 8     0     1     7    84 A8    A08   A     8     blue  
 9     0     1     8   109 A9    A09   A     9     blue  
10     0     1     9   110 A10   A10   A     10    blue  
# … with 80 more rows
```

Some parting thoughts:

- Using `wellmapr` decouples the layout from the analysis, which is a really good thing.  This makes it easy to reuse the same analysis scripts with different layouts, and to reuse the same layouts with different analysis scripts.
- I showed how to use `inner_join()` to merge the labels with the data, but `wellmapr::load()` can do this merge automatically.  It's actually better to let `wellmapr::load()` do the merge, because it handles a corner case relating to layouts that encompass multiple data files.  See the documentation for details.